# Инициализация NioClientSocketChannelFactory. Библиотека Netty.Java

Tags: java, netty

Инициализирую  NioClientSocketChannelFactory, а именно:

```
ChannelFactory factory = new NioClientSocketChannelFactory
```

(тредпулы). Он не понимает, откуда брать NioClientSocketChannelFactory.

Это не входит в библиотеку Nelly. Нашел библиотеку  org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketChannelFactory

Когда я её импортирую в jboss, в пути подсвечивается красным.

Я выбриаю: "Find Jar on WEB", он пишет: нет библиотеки по пути.

Как мне инициализировать NioClientSocketChannelFactory? Или это можно сделать по другому?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Класс `NioClientSocketChannelFactory` доступен в `netty 3`, где нет `ChannelFactory`. `ChannelFactory` доступен в `netty 5`, возможно, так же в 4.